# NON Equijoin for two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table I need to join this 2 tables but I don't have common column in both tables .table structure as below

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
        cust_id NUMBER
                                                 CONSTRAINT cus_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
        cust_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR2(40),
        contact_no NUMBER NOT NULL,
        email_id VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE TABLE supplier(
        supp_id NUMBER
                                                CONSTRAINT supp_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
        supp_name VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR2(40),
        contact_no NUMBER NOT NULL,
        email_id VARCHAR2(30));
```

question:
Create an SQL Query to list out all the customers and suppliers who have their contact_no as starting and ending with 9.

Answer (score 2):

A normal `UNION` should do it;

```
SELECT 'customer' type, cust_id id, cust_name name, address, contact_no, email_id
FROM customer WHERE contact_no LIKE '9%9'
 UNION
SELECT 'supplier' type, supp_id id, supp_name name, address, contact_no, email_id
FROM supplier WHERE contact_no LIKE '9%9'
```

EDIT: If you really want to `JOIN` with weak criteria, you can do it fairly easily;

```
SELECT c.cust_id, c.cust_name, c.address cust_addr,
   c.contact_no cust_contact_no, c.email_id cust_email_id,
   s.supp_id, s.supp_name, s.address supp_addr,
   s.contact_no supp_contact_no, s.email_id supp_email_id
FROM customer c
JOIN supplier s
  ON c.contact_no LIKE '9%9'
 AND s.contact_no LIKE '9%9';
```

[An SQLfiddle showing both](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fe61/1).

Comment: I need to display both customer details and supplier details.

Comment: @Ayeswarya See the update, if I misunderstood, you may have to clarify the question a bit with an example.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:-

```
    (SELECT * 
    FROM customer 
    WHERE contact_no LIKE '9%9')

    UNION ALL

   (SELECT * 
    FROM supplier 
    WHERE contact_no LIKE '9%9')
```

Comment: Yes, it's faster and easier to get all columns. But it's also dangerous and lazy.